# rails 2.3.5 failsafe error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, rvm

I installed ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 using rvm.I created my project and when i try to start the server using `script/server` i get this error

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-02-08 17:59:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-02-08 17:59:53] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28) [i686-darwin11.0.0]
[2012-02-08 17:59:53] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=14527 port=3000
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Feb 08 18:00:03 +0530 2012
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  no such file to load -- sqlite3
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:10:in `sqlite3_connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in `service'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    /Users/anandhegde/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

and when i open localhost:3000/trip in my browser it says
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

"We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have u install sqlite3 gem and its package

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the line `no such file to load -- sqlite3`. You need to install the sqlite3 gem with: `gem install sqlite3`.

I have to ask though, why are you using such an old version of Rails? If you need to stick to 2.3 then you should at least go for version 2.3.11.

Comment: because I'm using stuck using network solutions which only uses rails 2.3.5. My app is really static and I don't need an sqlite database or any database. Is there some way to tell rails to not look for sqlite?